# Choosing A Power Supply

Tags: power-supply

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Power Supply Capacity Formula](https://superuser.com/questions/16889/power-supply-capacity-formula)
>   [How can I check if my system needs more PSU power?](https://superuser.com/questions/167115/how-can-i-check-if-my-system-needs-more-psu-power)

I'm not sure if it's OK or not to ask a hardware question here.  If not please let me know a good place but I've always got good info here so I thought I'd give it a shot.

I'm custom building a new workstation for coding (Linux/Eclipse).  How do I determine how much power the power supply needs?  I'm building a mini ITX system on a budget and so I need to get as small as possible that is sufficient.

I'll have a mini itx mobo with on board wifi and bluetooth, 8 GB RAM, an Intel i3 3.1 Ghz processor, 64 GB SSD and a slim optical drive.  In the future I might add a descrete GPU, 16 GB RAM, 128 GB SSD.  What is the minimum power I need and how do I calculate that?

Comment: We have a [wonderful guide to the same topic](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/09/28/5-ways-of-finding-the-right-power-supply/)

Comment: Fixed. Apparently the link had a tail. It was chopped off and sent for scientific testing.

Comment: Build your system to handle the maximum possible power consumption.  Each component will typically have a maximum power draw listed on the manufacturer's website.  If you're unable to find this information there, look up reviews on that product.  Most reputable review sites will include typical power consumption and efficiency (if applicable).

Comment: Thank you, why did I lose 4 reputation for this? :-(  I searched the web first for help and I just got hundreds of store sites and advertisements.

Comment: I lost 4 reputation on stack overflow :'(